# Is there something equivalent to a file 'include' in webpack/node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, include

I'm working on a Webpack/VueCLI project which will serve javascript files for an external application. These files will be served to different 'projects', one file per project, and I'd like to have some common functionality in a base file, which is included in the project file.

I initially thought to have webpack's module/import handling do this:

```
//base.js

console.log('Base functionality')

//project-a.js

import './base.js';

console.log('Project functionality');
```

But this doesn't behave the way I want: Webpack resolves the modules, wraps them up in its own `__webpack_require__` functionality, etc.

I think what I *really* want is more like old-fashioned server-side includes: so the JS loader simply imports the contents of `base.js` wholesale and drops it into `project-a.js` at the appropriate spot.

Is there a way to make webpack/node (or something) do this?

Comment: Why exactly do you want that? Webpack takes care of embedding the code only once and inject it where it is being imported. The code would be duplicated for every import, with your requirement, which would drastically and needlessly increase the JavaScript bundle size. I'd say server-side includes are related to server-side rendered HTML, not JavaScript browser-rendered apps which is a completely different use case

Comment: This isn't for a browser-rendered app. I have this specialized requirement because I need to serve a javascript file to a separate application, and I need the context, variable names, etc to be fixed when it is used by the other application, not wrapped in Webpack's injection system - I'm serving a self-contained library, basically.

Comment: You may want to use something else than webpack then, because it's main purpose is to generate bundles for the browser.

Comment: @GuerricP - I suspect you might be right: I have that in my question. Do you know of an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest adapting your project slightly to work with Node's JS module system. This involves:

- Organizing the common code into discrete units (functions, classes, constants, etc)
- Giving these discrete units names.
- Requesting these names when importing.

**Here is an example of how to write common functionality in a base file:**

```
// base.js
export const PI = 3.14

export const sqrt = Math.sqrt;

export function square(x) {
    return x * x;
}

export function circleArea(r) {
    return PI * square(r);
}
```

**Then here is how to access that common functionality from a project file:**

```
// project-a.js
import { circleArea } from './base.js';

console.log('Area of circle with radius 10 is:');
console.log(circleArea(10));
```

---

JS `import`/`export` syntax can be confusing, so here is a useful guide:
[ES6 Import And Export Cheatsheet](https://dev.to/myogeshchavan97/es6-import-and-export-cheatsheet-3op5)

---

**update: How to output a bundle for each project:**

After organizing your code as described above, configure a bundler to output each project file as desired. They key is figuring out how to specify multiple input files and multiple output bundles. Almost any bundler will work:

- [ParcelJS](https://parceljs.org/)
- [WebPack](https://webpack.js.org/)
- [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/)
- [Rollup.js](https://rollupjs.org/)

I suggest Rollup because it requires the least configuration and seems to output what you want without any "overhead."

Continuing the example from above, this command:

```
$ rollup project-a.js --file output.js
```

produces this output:

```
// base.js
const PI = 3.14;

function square(x) {
    return x * x;
}

function circleArea(r) {
    return PI * square(r);
}

// project-a.js

console.log('Area of circle with radius 10 is:');
console.log(circleArea(10));
```

Notice the bundler was smart enough to notice `export const sqrt = Math.sqrt;` was not used and excluded this line from the output. This is why JS import statements require you to explicitly name the discrete units like `import { circleArea } from './base.js'`

Now, every JS bundler has a ton of [configuration options](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#command-line-reference) like minification, but I think this is enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks Leftium - this seems closer to what I want. However, is there some process which can actually 'resolve' or 'include' the import statements into the importing file? Does that even make sense? I'd like to include `project-a.js` in an external webpage, and have that be a self-contained file with the contents of both `base.js` and `project-a.js`.

Comment: @BenHull I am not aware of anything that does exactly what you want. JS bundlers like WebPack/Rollup can be configured to output multiple files like 'project-a.js' and 'project-b.js' but they do not maintain the exact text of the original input files. Perhaps if you explain *why* you need what you are looking for, I can explain how to use existing common practices/tools.

Comment: OK, so the use-case is that I have an application which I can only make minimal changes to, apart from injecting a `<script>` element to import `project-x.js`. I want to serve a really minimal JS file, with a set of basic functionality (from `base.js`) and then the project specific functionality with a single request. The whole file will be tiny - maybe 20kb max - so I don't want the overhead of `webpackJsonpCallback` and friends. I would like to be able to automate the build process though, and minify the JS (whitespace, etc) without munging it at all.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @BenHull I updated my answer with details about how to use a JS bundler.